# highlithed cell collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, nsdate

I've created a calendar using a collection view but I need that today's day be highlighted in the collection view.

I'll explain.

Today is September 8. In my collectionView I would like the cell containing the number 8 to be filled with red color.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellId = @"dayCell";
    static BOOL xibLoaded = NO;

    if (!xibLoaded) {
        UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"UPCalendarCell" bundle:nil];
        [collectionView registerNib:nib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellId];
        xibLoaded = YES;
    }

    UPCalendarCell *cell = (UPCalendarCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

    /***** ARRAY WITH WEEKDAY *****/
    NSString *cellData = [_day objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.weekday.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", cellData];

    /***** ARRAY WITH DAY NUMBER *****/
    NSString *day = [_numberDay objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.day.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", day];

    /*******************************************
     *******************************************
     if today's number is in the collection view, highlight the corresponding cell
     *******************************************
     *******************************************/

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date]; // CURRENT DATE
    NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];  // CURRENT CALENDAR
    NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:currentDate]; // FETCH CURRENT DAY NUMBER

    NSInteger numbers = [components day];
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:numbers];

    if ([_numberDay containsObject:number]) {
        NSLog(@"YES");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"NO");
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you need help setting the color or do you need help determine if the cell represents "today"?

Comment: I need to represent if the cell represents today and then color the label text

Comment: Do you need help with matching today's date with your calendar data in order to determine a match, or are you needing help with changing the appearance of the UICollectionViewCell?